# como cambiar el tipo de letra en un reporte PDF datatables js?

Tags: datatables

Tengo la siguiente duda.

Como hago para cambiar el tipo de letra, etc.
en un reporte PDF datatables js

Muchas gracias.
esto es lo que tengo

```
buttons: [
        {

            extend: 'colvis',
            extend: 'pdfHtml5', 

            header: true,
            //title: 'SYSCOMBUS - SISTEMA DE CONTROL DE COMBUSTIBLE',
            orientation: '',
            pageSize: 'letter',
            fontSize: '6',
            exportOptions : {
              columns : [0,1,2,3,4,5,6], 
                stripHtml : false 
                },
            customize: function ( doc ) {
                 doc.styles.tableHeader = {
                     fillColor:'#525659',
                     color:'#FFF',
                     fontSize: '8',
                     alignment: 'left',
                     bold: true 

                  }, //para cambiar el backgorud del escabezado
                 doc.defaultStyle.fontSize = 9;
                 doc.pageMargins = [50,50,30,30];//left,top,right,bottom

                doc.content[1].margin = [ 5, 0, 0, 5], // margenes para la datables
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a que leas cómo crear un [mcve] para poder ver qué has intentado y pueda ser más fácil ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Como indicas el fontSize por ejemplo, también puedes indicar el fontFamily.
Por ejemplo: `font-family: Verdana, "Times New Roman", sans-serif;`

Información que podría servirte: [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](http://help.dottoro.com/ljasicbt.php)

Espero que sea de ayuda, si no es exacto lo que necesitas, puedes comentar para ver si puedo ayudar mejor.Saludos!

Comment: gracias por responder : probe con font-family,falla en la sintaxis

Answer (score 0):

intenta con esto.

```
doc.defaultStyle.font = 'Arial';
```

Esta línea hace que que cambies el formato del tipo de letra.

Suerte.

Comment: Gracias por ayudar, pero esa linea de codigo no me funciona, lo que lei es que tengo que hacer modificacion al archivo vfs_font.js de datables , por que trae por defecto el font Roboto, pero lo deje por la paz , lei algo de base64 , pero no di con bola